can we only consume backends to be part of internal standard load balancer when using private link service between Azure subscriptions
I want to expose my Azure database for the sql server through a private link service, So I won't be able to add that as a backend in the ILB,
can we only expose services that are part of ILB backned using private link service? if not then what should be the subresource name as a part of private link connection

An Internal Load Balancer (ILB) is not necessary to expose an Azure SQL Database via Azure Private Link. Private Link enables a direct connection to Azure SQL Database from your Virtual Network, which increases security without the need for an ILB. During the setup of Private Link for a SQL Database, there is no need for a specific subresource name because the service is directly targeted. You can establish a private endpoint within your Virtual Network for a direct connection to the SQL Database. @chandrashekar
